# ¿Como agrego filas a un tbody con jquery?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, bootstrap

Estoy trabajando con jquery, el problema es que cuando yo cargo las filas al tbody, se deparece el thead de mi tabla.

```
$('#tblinvoice tbody').append(fila);
```

fila esta el codigo html el cual se deberia intertar al tbody de mi tabla sin embargo desaparece al cargar las filas.

```
$('#tblinvoice').append(fila);
```

si cargo solo llamando a mi tabla, aparece las filas pero desaparece el encabezado, osea el thead

Answer (score 2):

Agregale un id a tu tbody, y en el append, agrega el identificador del tbody.

Asi deberia de quedar tu tbody

```
<tbody id="my_tbody">
```

Y asi deberia de quedar tu append

```
$('#my_tbody').append(fila);
```

Ejemplo:

```js
var i = 1;

function agregar(){

 

 var contenido = '<tr>';
 contenido += '<td>Nombre '+i+'</td>';
 contenido += '<td>Apellido '+i+'</td>';
 contenido += '<td>Correo '+i+'</td>';
 contenido += '</tr>';
 $('#my_tbody').append(contenido);
 
 i++;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>
  <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="agregar()">Agregar fila</button></p>            
  <table class="table">
    <thead id="my_thead">
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="my_tbody">
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```